# MySQL trigger: convert text to numbers

Tags: php, mysqli, triggers

I have a table with these fields:

```
users {id,name,week1,week2,week3,overall_score}
```

The weeks are TEXT and the overall_score is an INT

In week one either `Absent` or `Present` is put into it. `Absent` is 0 points and `Present` is 10. I would like to create a trigger to run automatically after each update to calculate the overall score and convert the text to a number.

Comment: Have you looked at any tutorials yet? What code have you come up with so far?

Comment: I have other tiggers , but dont know how to convert the text to a number

Comment: In that case it would be worth having a go at writing the trigger and post what you come up with here. Also, it might be worth including the data types of your fields.

Comment: ...and do the weeks only contain numbers, or is there a suffix (e.g. " points") appended to them?

Comment: No , the weeks hold either the word Absent or Present. I would like the trigger to when run look at all the text in a row and work out the score. Or would it just be easier to put in 0 and 10 from the start and just use sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go about solving this problem using the following 2 steps:

1. Create a function to determine the score for a particular week...

   ```
   DELIMITER //

   CREATE FUNCTION `GetWeekScore`(`WeekAttendance` TEXT) RETURNS INT
   BEGIN
     IF WeekAttendance = 'Present' THEN
       RETURN 10;
     ELSE
       RETURN 0;
     END IF;
   END//

   DELIMITER ;
   ```
2. Use that function in a trigger...

   ```
   DELIMITER //

   CREATE TRIGGER `CalculateOverallScore` BEFORE UPDATE ON `users`
     FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
       SET NEW.overall_score = (GetWeekScore(NEW.week1) + 
                                GetWeekScore(NEW.week2) +
                                GetWeekScore(NEW.week3));
     END//

   DELIMITER ;
   ```

Comment: the create function doesn't work - #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Comment: the trigger isnt working - #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8

Comment: Apologies - as I said it was untested. I've now had a chance to test it and it works correctly. I've edited the trigger code such that "AFTER UPDATE" has become "BEFORE UPDATE" and body of trigger has been updated (no UPDATE statement necessary as it's operating on the same table).